# How to create an INSERT IGNORE query in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate has to make inserts in a table which has an unique field. I want to ignore duplicate entries so that my program keeps running. In MySQL I would simply say `INSERT IGNORE`, but I can't figure out how to do that in Hibernate. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using a simple SQL query,
use following code.

```
               Query query = session.createSQLQuery("INSERT IGNORE INTO user (name,username) VALUES (:name,:username)");
               query.setParameter("name", name);
               query.setParameter("username", username);
               int i= query.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried using the `@SQLInsert` [annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch18.html#querysql-cud) ? This way, you can overwrite the Hibernate statement with your own custom SQL and use `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
@SQLInsert(sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO CUSTOMER(id,name) VALUES(?,?)")
class Customer{
   ...
}
```